# Expected number of trials to get 5 heads

Tags: expected-value, bernoulli-distribution

Say I have a fair coin. I want to know the expected number of trials to get 5 heads.

What is the relationship to the following idea:
$E[$number of heads in n trials$]= (1/2 \cdot 1+1/2 \cdot 0) \cdot n= 5$

$\rightarrow$ n= 10

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102673/what-is-the-expected-number-of-trials-until-x-successes

Comment: Thank you! but is it correct to solve for n as in E[number of heads in n trials]=5? say the probability of the ith head is no longer independent of previous events, so I no longer have a geometric distribution to count the number of trials in between heads.

Comment: In your case  $success= heads$ with $p=0.5$. For the expected number of successes in $n$ trials, I believe you just multiply $n*p$.